# How to use apply in a Pandas dataframe slice to set values of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to use apply function to assign new values to two existing columns in a dataframe slice using a .loc query.

To reproduce - first create a dataframe:

```
import re
import panads as pd
data = [[1000, "MSL", "Test string"], [2000, 'AGL', 'other string'], [0, 'AGL', "xxxx SFC-10000ft MSLXXX"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Alt', "AltType",'FreeText'])
```

Then create the apply function

```
def testapply(row):
    try:
        match = re.findall("SFC-([0-9]+)FT (MSL|AGL|FL)", row.FreeText)[0]
        return (int(match[0]), match[1])
    except:
        return (0, row.AltType)
```

When I run

```
df.loc[df['Alt']==0, ['Alt', 'AltType']] = df.loc[df['Alt']==0].apply(testapply, axis=1)
```

I would like to get as a result is:

```
     Alt AltType                 FreeText
0   1000     MSL              Test string
1   2000     AGL             other string
2  10000     MSL  xxxx SFC-10000ft MSLXXX
```

but what I end up getting is:

```
            Alt       AltType                 FreeText
0          1000           MSL              Test string
1          2000           AGL             other string
2  (10000, MSL)  (10000, MSL)  xxxx SFC-10000FT MSLXXX
```

Does anyone know how to make this work in one fell swoop?

Comment: I explained in my answer you need to return a list instead of tuple. the problem will be solved by adding a tolist() at the end of return (int(match[0]), match[1]) in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `tolist()`

```
df.loc[df['Alt']==0, ['Alt', 'AltType']] = df.loc[df['Alt']==0].apply(testapply, axis=1).tolist()
```

Comment: Chaining tolist to the apply function is what worked for me, not converting the return value from within the apply function. as @mhDG7 specified.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `Series.str.extract` and use boolean indexing with `loc` to replace the values in columns `Alt` and `AltType` where the column `Alt` contains `0`:

```
m = df['Alt'].eq(0)
df.loc[m, ['Alt', 'AltType']] = df.loc[m, 'FreeText'].str.extract(r'(?i)SFC-(\d+)FT\s(MSL|AGL|FL)').values
```

---

```
     Alt AltType                 FreeText
0   1000     MSL              Test string
1   2000     AGL             other string
2  10000     MSL  xxxx SFC-10000ft MSLXXX
```

Comment: This would technically work except in the more general case of more complicated workflows.  I simplified my actual code for the purposes of this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use loc accessor to select relevant `Alt` column. Compute value  by extracting `digit` from matching `FreeText` using `regex`

```
df.loc[df['Alt']==0,'Alt']=df.loc[df['Alt']==0,'FreeText'].str.extract('(\d+)')[0]



     Alt AltType                 FreeText
0   1000     MSL              Test string
1   2000     AGL             other string
2  10000     AGL  xxxx SFC-10000ft MSLXXX
```

Comment: This would technically work except in the more general case of more complicated workflows. I simplified my actual code for the purposes of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Only change your testapply function to this:

```
def testapply(row):
    try:
        match = re.findall("SFC-([0-9]+)ft (MSL|AGL|FL)", row.FreeText)[0]
        print(match)
        return (int(match[0]), match[1]).tolist()
    except:
        return (0, row.AltType)
```